# store function output in matrix in R

Tags: r, function, return

When I run a function in R, I use the "Return" command to display, but when I use this it seems like I can only return one matrix, and then only in the Console i.e. it doesn't store it as a matrix in my objects window.

My question is this: how do I store the matrices created in a function as matrices which can be accessed and viewed after the function has finished running through the workspace window?

Oh, I'm using RStudio as my editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Just assign it to something. `A <- myfun(blahblah); A`. `A` should now be in your workspace. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: If you need to return more than one variable from a function wrapping them all into `list()` and returning that will work

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on.
`return` prints your data to the console, as you observed.
EDIT: to clarify, the `print` method, as Roland pointed out, does the printing.  The result of whatever the last operation in your function is will be printed to the console. Since `return` terminates the function, the result of `return` is what's picked up by `print` .

However, **printing** things, be it with `return` or `print` or other commands, does just that: puts stuff in the window.  As it happens,  `return` does another thing: it sends the data to the recipient object if there is a `->` or `<-` assignment operator (or some other operators, but leave that be for now).

`return` dumps the data into an ephemeral object which can be retrieved in the very next command (only) with `.Last.value` .

You can also write `return(invisible(mydata))` to suppress printing to the console while still making the data available for assignment.

Comment: I don't think `return` does any printing. That is done by the `print` method.

Comment: @Roland  Doesn't the `print` method automagically printout the result of the last operation in a function?  I admit to being a bit glib there, but since `return` terminates a function, it all comes out the same in the end.